# How to send Array as Body to a Web Service in android with Volley library?

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to send a data as an array to a web service and I using Volley library to do that, but in a part of my code I should send an Array as Body. So I'm using the below code for another part of my project then give a JSON object as a body but now I want to send a body as an array.
my array

```
[
  {
    "name": "a",
    "family": "f"
  },
  {
    "name": "b",
    "family": "f"
  },
  {
    "name": "c",
    "family": "f"
  }
]

String url = "";
            try {
                JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
                jsonBody.put("name", name); 
                jsonBody.put("family", family); 
                //request a json object response
                JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest( Request.Method.POST, url, jsonBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }) {    //this is the part, that adds the header to the request
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                        return params;
                    }
                };
                // Add the request to the queue
                Volley.newRequestQueue(Activity_Goods_List.this).add(jsonRequest);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Comment: I wanted to add this below your new question, posted as an answer, but that was removed before I could finish. Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it's a Q&A repository. That means every new problem must be asked in a new question. Also, it's important to mark any contribution that answers your question as "the" answer by clicking on the checkmark at its left. This helps the site quality by telling others what helped and that the question is taken care of. Also, it thanks the person who put in the work and time to help with site points.

Answer (score 1):

Add your objects to array-like this

Let us assume you have a list of names and family

```
    JSONArray request=new JSONArray();
    for(int i=0; i<names.size; i++){
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        jsonBody.put("name", names.get(i));
        jsonBody.put("family", family.get(i));
        request.put(jsonBody);
    }
    // You'll have array ready here for your request
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send as a `json` array. Encode the Array into JSON and sent to your backed. From your backend, you can parse JSON and retrieve back the array. You can't directly send the array, You have to follow data transfer formats like `json` or `xml`

Comment: thanks for your attention. dear I'm using Json format. but what I should do for that. you said I should send as json array but how to can do that

Comment: `JSONArray mJSONArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(mStringArray));` or you can use Json Library like `Gson`